# How can I improve efficiency while inserting many (+200) rows of dataframe in Django models?

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe, django-models

```py
for transaction in df.itertuples():
    transaction_obj = Transactions()
    transaction_obj.portfolio = strategy.portfolio
    transaction_obj.strategy = strategy
    transaction_obj.transaction_price = transaction.TransactionPrices
    transaction_obj.time_stamp = transaction[0]
    transaction_obj.transaction_type = name
    transaction_obj.brokerage = transaction.Brokerage

    if name == Transactions.LONG:
        if transaction.EntryLong:
            transaction_obj.action = Transactions.BUY
        if transaction.ExitLong:
            transaction_obj.action = Transactions.SELL
    elif name == Transactions.SHORT:
        if transaction.EntryShort:
            transaction_obj.action = Transactions.SELL
        if transaction.ExitShort:
            transaction_obj.action = Transactions.BUY

    transaction_obj.save()
```

The code works fine with no problems or errors, however I want to reduce the execution time. Currently, it takes around 7 seconds to insert the 180 lines of rows. I am using a PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your script suppose to always create record (not modify), then you can optimize creation time by using [Bulk create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/optimization/#create-in-bulk):

```
transactions = []
for transaction in df.itertuples():
    transaction_obj = Transactions()
    transaction_obj.portfolio = strategy.portfolio
    transaction_obj.strategy = strategy
    transaction_obj.transaction_price = transaction.TransactionPrices
    transaction_obj.time_stamp = transaction[0]
    transaction_obj.transaction_type = name
    transaction_obj.brokerage = transaction.Brokerage

    if name == Transactions.LONG:
        if transaction.EntryLong:
            transaction_obj.action = Transactions.BUY
        if transaction.ExitLong:
            transaction_obj.action = Transactions.SELL
    elif name == Transactions.SHORT:
        if transaction.EntryShort:
            transaction_obj.action = Transactions.SELL
        if transaction.ExitShort:
            transaction_obj.action = Transactions.BUY

    transactions.append(transaction_obj)
Transaction.objects.bulk_create(transactions)
```